# Publishing a web application with an executable to MS Azure

Tags: azure

Here is my situation, I have a web app that contains:

- An .exe (which is a .net project along with assembly files and so on)
- ZIPped xml files
- Folders containing js&css files

Now when executing the .exe it parses the xml inside the ZIPs to create html files( the end result is a complete html that imports some of the js libraries and css files).
Considering that I have basic experience in MS Azure, I am looking for a way to have my application run on azure? My guess is that the ZIPped xmls could be stored most probably using blob storage along with the js and css files. What I am not sure of is how to get the executable running there(Possibly deploying the .exe with its corresponding resources,assemblies,dlls etc...) and have it execute from there.

Comment: This isn't deployment of a Web Application, you are actually creating a new web application on the spot by running an executable. You can only do this if you have your own VM. The web site related services are about deploying web sites in one form or another, nor running arbitrary scripts. Why don't you use one of the available publishing mechanisms?

Comment: Hmm I understand but how can I have the .exe then run on an azure site?

Comment: You can't, you don't even have a site - you have a script that will create a site. You can only run such a thing if you have your own VM. Web Roles allow you to run startup scripts, but even these require that you *actually have* a site.

Comment: so all I have to do is create a dummy a site no? I mean I deployed an MVC app before from visual studio to an azure site and basically all it does is display cshtml pages accordingly. I still don't understand why it s not possible to either go from visual studio or directly by modifying things in a site using ftp or something similar.

Comment: Why are you trying to duplicate what Azure does? What are you trying to do? Azure's Web App and Web Role allow you to package and configure a web application, upload the package to one or more servers and deploy the content automatically. You are trying to do some part of this process manually, in a dangerous way that may not even be allowed for security reasons.

Comment: Well I haven't done anything and still figure out how to go about it. All I am trying to do is have my application run on an Azure site. Though it is not clear to me, but are you saying that it is possible using my current resources?

Comment: Make your web application deployed onto Azure Web Sites rather than on Azure cloud service as a Web Role, which will enable you to access the published files over FTP and can let you do on the fly changes through FTP file updates. For ref http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/windows-azure-website-uploading-downloading-files-over-ftp-and-collecting-diagnostics-logs.aspx

Comment: I see. Since I only have the executable I am thinking of using ILSpy to generate all the corresponding source code and its solution in order to publish it using visual studio. As for the zip files I am thinking of either putting them in blob containers or maybe insert them over ftp.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos after some investigation I understand your point now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a home grown build process (your exe) then you need to use cloud services (your own VM) where you can run this and expose your website over whatever ports you want. However it sounds like you are new to .Net, I'd suggest reading up on ASP.Net MVC Web Projects. That way you can leverage Visual Studio for building the website and deploy to a Azure Website, which is designed to host websites.